# How to make right url address in Yii2

Tags: php, url, yii2

I need to do an url address that looks like *website/user/username* where *username* is coming from database. I've tried to reach it by placing a $user variable in my action function as a parameter and result looks like this *website/action?user=username*. But it looks kind of hinty and ugly. How can I get a desirable result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to configure url rules in  config/web.php.

```
[
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enableStrictParsing' => false,
        'rules' => [
            "user/<username:\w+>"=> "controller/action"
        ],
    ],
],
```

]

And add url match condition in rules array like 
`"user/<username:\w+>"=> "controller/action"`

Create. htaccess file with below url condition in web folder

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

And generate urls with Url helper class or Html class like below

```
echo Url::to(['controller/action', 'username' => 'jack']);

Or 

echo Html::a('Profile', ['controller/action', 'username' => 'jack'], ['class' => 'profile-link'])
```

**Note:-** controller name, action name and username should match with Url condition. Which we define in rules array.